# Triple Quotes when saving an excel file as csv VBA

Tags: excel, vba, quotes, double-quotes

I'm getting triple quotes on each cell when saving an excel file as CSV, it needs to be like `"Hello World"` but I'm getting `"""Hello World"""` when I open the CSV file. the CSV is comma delimited

edit: if I save it without the quotes, its save like `Hello world`

```
Do While xExcelFile <> ""
    newFileName = Replace(xExcelFile, " ", "_")

'*****************************************************
    For Each c In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            c.Value = Chr(34) & c.Value & Chr(34)
        End If
    Next c
'******************************************************
    'Saving file as csv
SaveFile:
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=xSPath & newFileName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'workbooks transformed log into cells
    Cells(cont, 6).Value = newFileName
    cont = cont + 1

NextLoop:
    'next file
    xExcelFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: If you need it to literally be `"Hello World"` with ONE double quote around each end of the word, then excel will escape those single double quotes with another double quote, as the double quote is the string encapsulation character that excel uses when writing as a "CSV" format. If your string that you are saving to CSV has a comma or a double quote in it, it will gain double quote string encapsulation and that string encapsulation character will be escaped.

Comment: @BigBen if I save it without the quotes, its save like `Hello world`

Comment: I think your misusing the Dir function, because the loop obviously ran 3 times  so you have triple quotes. Let us see the whole code to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim xSpath As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    xSpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    newFileName = "test1"

    Set rngDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    TransToCsv rngDB, XPath & newFileName & ".csv"
End Sub

Sub TransToCsv(rngDB As Range, strFile As String)
    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strTxt As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    vDB = rngDB

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            If IsNumeric(vDB(i, j)) Then
                vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
            Else
                vR(j) = Chr(34) & vDB(i, j) & Chr(34)
            End If
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strTxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile strFile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, i have a question, what does it means `.SaveToFile strFile, 2` the "2" on this line ?

Comment: @JoseChiesa,
 adSaveCreateNotExist 1 Default. Creates a new file if the file specified by the FileName parameter does not already exist. // adSaveCreateOverWrite 2 Overwrites the file with the data from the currently open Stream object, if the file specified by the Filename parameter already exists. If the file specified by the Filename parameter does not exist, a new file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Using this part of your code:

```
'*****************************************************
    For Each c In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            c.Value = Chr(34) & c.Value & Chr(34)
        End If
    Next c
'******************************************************
    'Saving file as csv
SaveFile:
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\teststs" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

My file saves fine with one set of double quotes as expected... so maybe the problem lies somewhere else within your code. What is the path you are saving to? Is it the same as the folder you are loading the excel files from?

Thinking you might be looping through the CSV's as well, hence the extra quotes...

Comment: HI @DarXyde thanks for your answer, the loop only searches xls/xlsx files, and the csv file is saved in the same path as the excel files

Comment: I don't see nothing in your DIR that stops the while loop to go through CSV files too, just saying. Try changing your save path to a different folder and see if there is a difference.