# VBA: from array to csv, keep long numbers as text

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv

I am trying to export an array directly to a csv file using the code from here: [Create CSV from array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191560/create-csv-from-array-in-vba/10313737#10313737).

The array contains large numbers I need to preserve as text but as usual Excel is forcing scientific notation upon the data instead.

I have some tricks that normally will preserve the long text format but they don´t work here.

I have tried tinkering here:

```
   For n = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 1)
    sCSV = ""
    For M = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 2)
      sCSV = sCSV & Format(MyArray(n, M)) & sDelimiter
    Next M
    sCSV = Left(sCSV, Len(sCSV) - 1) 'remove last Delimiter
    Print #7, sCSV
  Next n
```

using

```
sCSV = sCSV & "'" & Format(MyArray(n, M)) & sDelimiter
```

and

```
sCSV = sCSV & cstr(Format(MyArray(n, M))) & sDelimiter
```

and

```
sCSV = sCSV & Format(MyArray(n, M), "General") & sDelimiter
```

but none of them has the desired result

The values in MyArray all have the right format.

Any suggestions

And yes, Excel/VBA is usually not the right tool for manipulating large amount of data. In this case I am bound by predefined workflow that occationally DO involve using worksheets so I am afraid there is no way around that...

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451389/triple-quotes-when-saving-an-excel-file-as-csv-vba/53453989?r=SearchResults#53453989)

Comment: Try sCSV = sCSV & chr$(34) & Format(MyArray(n, M)) & chr$(34) & sDelimiter

Comment: Hi. Dy Lee an Freeflow. I appriciate the help. Unfortunetly it didn´t change anything. It just put the trucnated value in quotes.

Comment: Then the problem may lie in the use of Format.  Try replacing format with cstr (as well as chr$(34)).  Format is a rather heavy duty function for a simple conversion of number to string.

Comment: sCSV = sCSV & CStr(MyArray(n, M)) & sDelimiter did the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Freeflow I found a solution. The VBA was overengineered. Cut out the format and use

```
sCSV = sCSV & MyArray(n, M) & sDelimiter
```

instead worked. Didn´t even need cstr()

Answer (score 0):

You need to you the Format function like this:

```
Format(MyArray(n, M),"#")
```

This forces only digits to be in the resultant string. If you have decimals, then "#.#" will accommodate that; however, the period (".") will always be present in the output, even if there are no decimals.